# GCP Load Balancer vs Cloudflare Forwarding Rules

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudflare, google-cloud-load-balancer

I'm very green on running servers, so I'm trying to understand the trade-offs. It seems to me that the primary benefit for using a GCP load balancer would be to have a layer of indirection that could be changed at runtime. i.e. if some disaster happens in my GCP region, and it knocks everything out of commission, I can then spin up my servers quickly in another region, modify my loadbalancer to instead point there, and I'm back up and running in a matter of hours with no altered clients.

Load Balancers are expensive though. It seems like I could get the same level of benefit from using Cloudflare Forwarding Rules. This doesn't seem to be a common practice though.

What am I not realizing? What additional benefits are there to me going with the GCP load balancer, instead of using Cloudflare Forwarding Rules?